# Intrinsic Matrix vs Perspective projection matrix

Tags: 3d, projections, camera-matrix

I was going through the camera matrix explained in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) article and understand how the matrix **K** \begin{bmatrix}f_x&s&x_0\\0&f_y&y_0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} is [built](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/). The projection matrix is then essentially `K * [R | T]`

However, I am not able to understand what the [perspective projection](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/how-to-derive-a-perspective-projection-matrix-from-its-components) matrix is and how is it same to the intrinsic matrix **K**

Comment: *"The **projection matrix is then essentially...".*   AFAICS That's not a projection matrix.. it's not really a "2D" rotation + translation matrix either.         Are you familiar with homogeneous coordinates? You really need to understand those first.

Comment: @SimonF this matrix can be easily broken into 2D Scaling "+" 2D translation. Also, this is essentially the simple perspective projection matrix. (multiply by it and then homogenise the co-ordinates.)

Comment: @SimonF I now understand that the projection matrix (with the viewing frustum mapped to a cube) is used as it contains depth information which is lost in the simple perspective projection matrix I had written earlier.

Comment: Oh good. :-)  FWIW my first comment was that you'd written [R|T] which seemed to me to imply **Rotation** +Scaling, but the matrix requires another term.

Answer (score 1):

> The projection matrix is then essentially `K * [R | T]`

Is incorrect, actually the K Matrix is similar to projection matrix and
the R|T is called *camera transform matrix* or *view transform matrix*
Or called *extrinsic matrix*. So focus on the projection stuff and forget about camera transform,
what is the difference between *K Matrix* and Perspective Projection
Matrix(call it *P Matrix* later)?

- For *K Matrix* it transform 3D points to 2D pixels in image space.
- For *P Matrix* it transform 3D points to NDC space.

Take a look at two matrices:

$$K = \begin{bmatrix}f_x&   0&  c_x\\  0& f_y&  c_y\\
0  &  0 &    1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{t*a}&   0&  0& 0\\0& \frac{1}{t}&  0& 0\\
0  &  0 &    A& B&\\ 0  &  0 &    -1& 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$t=tan(\frac{fovy}{2})$$
$$a=\frac{width}{height}$$

Let's add perspective divide and show the result of the above two matrices:

Intrinsic case: $$x_{2d} = \frac{x_0}{z_0 * \frac{1}{f_x}} + c_x$$

Perspective case: $$x_{2d} = \frac{x_0}{-z_0(t*a)}$$

Similar with some difference.

The image space: Origin from left-top corner
so should add Cx Cy as the offset from center to left-top corner.
And in NDC space we assume Z-axis direct out of screen so P(3,2) = -1.